# Extract columns from a create statements DDL file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, sh

How to extract the column names and data types from each table in the below DDL file.

```
-- Create statement 1
-- Some text

Create table Test1(
        id int,
        name string
);
Create table Test2(
        id int,
        city string
)
```

Output should look like below for each table -

```
[{"column":"id","dataType":"int"},
{"column":"name","dataType":"string"}]

[{"column":"id","dataType":"int"},
{"column":"city","dataType":"string"}]
```

Comment: Which dialect of SQL?

Comment: I think my SQL is database agnostic. I want to bring the specfied output in Shell script.

Comment: Which SQL dialects allow "string" as a type?

Comment: Hive Query Language(HQL)